# Passing a lambda that captures as argument to a function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functor

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72156109/4504465).

In that question I had a function `package` with a function pointer as a parameter. The signature of the functions it accepted looked like this:

```
template <typename WidgetType, typename Deleter, typename... Dependencies>
using FactoryFunction = std::unique_ptr<WidgetType, Deleter>(*)(std::shared_ptr<Dependencies>...);
```

And the signature of `package` looked like this:

```
template <typename WidgetType, typename Deleter, typename... Dependencies>
void package(FactoryFunction<WidgetType, Deleter, Dependencies...> factoryFunction)
```

I was able to pass a lambda to `package` by using the unary operator:

```
package(+[]{return std::make_unique<Foo>()});
```

All well and good, unless I need to capture something in the lambda passed to `package`. If I change the alias `FactoryFunction` to:

```
template <typename WidgetType, typename Deleter, typename... Dependencies>
using FactoryFunction = std::function<std::unique_ptr<WidgetType, Deleter>(std::shared_ptr<Dependencies>...)>;
```

Then I can pass a capturing lambda to `package` by doing:

```
std::function<std::unique_ptr<Foo>()> fooer = [i](){
    return std::make_unique<Foo>();
};

package(fooer);
```

As mentioned in the original question, this is quite verbose, and it involves a good amount of redundancy, especially when there are more dependency types.

```
std::function<std::unique_ptr<Bar>(
    std::shared_ptr<Foo>, std::shared_ptr<Bif>, std::shared_ptr<Baz>)> barer= 
        [i](std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo, std::shared_ptr<Bif> bif, std::shared_ptr<Baz> baz) {
            return std::make_unique<Bar>(foo, bif, baz);
        };

package(fooer);
```

How can I write the signature of `package` so that I can call `package` with something as succinct as:

```
package([capturedVar](std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo, std::shared_ptr<Bif> bif, std::shared_ptr<Baz> baz) {
    foo->proccess(capturedVar);
    return std::make_unique<Bar>(foo, bif, baz);
});
```

For posterity, here's the code from the original question.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>

// Template alias for widget factory.
template <typename WidgetType, typename Deleter, typename... Dependencies>
using FactoryFunction = std::unique_ptr<WidgetType, Deleter> (*)(std::shared_ptr<Dependencies>...);

// A pair of widgets, one dependant on the other.
struct Foo {
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo constructed.\n"; }
};
struct Bar {
    Bar(std::shared_ptr<Foo> f) : f_(f) { std::cout << "Bar constructed from Foo ptr.\n"; }
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> f_;
};

// Factory functions to make widgets.
std::unique_ptr<Foo> makeFoo() { return std::make_unique<Foo>(); }
std::unique_ptr<Bar> makeBar(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo) { return std::make_unique<Bar>(foo); }

// Map of factory functions packaged into function of signature void(), keyed by the type index of the widget type it makes.
std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void()>> packagedFactories;

// Final resting place of a factory function.
template <typename WidgetType, typename Deleter, typename... Dependencies>
std::shared_ptr<WidgetType> accept(FactoryFunction<WidgetType, Deleter, Dependencies...> factoryFunction) {
    return std::invoke(factoryFunction, std::make_shared<Dependencies>()...);

    // This part has a bit more going on in the real code.
    // Rather than making a new widget for each dependency,
    // dependencies are created elsewhere and fetched.
    // Something like:
 // return std::invoke(factoryFunction, getWidget<Dependencies>()...);
}

// Package a factory for later invocation.
template <typename WidgetType, typename Deleter, typename... Dependencies>
void package(FactoryFunction<WidgetType, Deleter, Dependencies...> factoryFunction) {
    auto tIndex = std::type_index(typeid(WidgetType));

    packagedFactories[tIndex] = [factoryFunction]() { accept(factoryFunction); };
}

void someFunc() {

    package(makeFoo);
    // package(+[]() { return std::unique_ptr<Foo>; }); // This works too.

    int i = 6;

    package(makeBar);
//  package([i](std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo) {  // <- This gives me errors.
//      foo->processThing(i);
//      return std::make_unique<Bar>(foo);
//  }

    packagedFactories[std::type_index(typeid(Foo))]();
    packagedFactories[std::type_index(typeid(Bar))]();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { someFunc(); }
```

Comment: Do you need to use `WidgetType`, `Deleter`, and `Dependencies...` in your `package` function?  If not, then `void package(auto factoryFunction)` would be sufficient.  Maybe add some `static_assert`s (or `requires` in C++20) to give nice error messages if `factoryFunction` doesn't fulfil the requirements you want.

Comment: Not a full answer but a rough sketch at least: Let the function accept auto, then use a struct with a template deduction guide to first get at a member function pointer ```&LambdaType::operator()```, put that into the struct and let the struct extract the argument and return value types. Then your ```package``` function can instantiate that struct template with the lambda type to get the various types and package it all up in an appropriate std::function.

Comment: @MilesBudnek `package` needs to see `WidgetType`. It wraps the `FactoryFunction` in a lambda with signature `void()`, then puts that into an `unordered_map` keyed by the `type_index` of `WidgetType`. Within that wrapping lambda, another function, `accept`, is called. `accept` needs to see the `Dependencies...` types.

Comment: @JonathanS. That sounds... promising. But I haven't the slightest idea what that would look like. Can I see some code? Or a link to an answer doing something along those lines? The linked question has a section at the end that compiles and runs, if you'd like to try to work in what you're talking about.

Comment: Looking at your full example, you could just make `FactoryFunction` be `std::function<std::unique_ptr<Widget, Deleter>(std::shared_ptr<Dependencies>...)>` and let class template argument deduction do its thing.  [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b560941e5a968d5).  Having to use an explicit `std::function{...}` is slightly less than ideal, but its much simpler than the alternative.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Well, that works great! Here I though I had to write out the whole template every time I wanted to make a FactoryFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to let template argument deduction deduce `WidgetType` and `Dependencies...`, it may be better to let `package` accept *any* type, and design type traits to figure out `WidgetType` and `Dependencies` from that.

Possible implementation:

```
template <typename T>
struct FunctionTraits
{
    using ReturnType = typename FunctionTraits<decltype(&T::operator())>::ReturnType;
    using ArgumentTypes = typename FunctionTraits<decltype(&T::operator())>::ArgumentTypes;
};

template <typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct FunctionTraits<Ret(T::*)(Args...)>
{
    using ReturnType = Ret;
    using ArgumentTypes = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct FunctionTraits<Ret(T::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using ReturnType = Ret;
    using ArgumentTypes = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct FunctionTraits<Ret(*)(Args...)>
{
    using ReturnType = Ret;
    using ArgumentTypes = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename T>
struct ArgsTuple;

template <typename... Args>
struct ArgsTuple<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Args>...>>
{
    static auto make()
    {
        return std::make_tuple(std::make_shared<Args>()...);
    }
};

std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void()>> packagedFactories;

template <typename FactoryFunction>
auto accept(FactoryFunction factoryFunction) {
    auto args = ArgsTuple<typename FunctionTraits<FactoryFunction>::ArgumentTypes>::make();
    return std::apply(factoryFunction, args);
}

template <typename FactoryFunction>
void package(FactoryFunction factoryFunction) {
    using WidgetType = typename FunctionTraits<FactoryFunction>::ReturnType::element_type;
    auto tIndex = std::type_index(typeid(WidgetType));

    packagedFactories[tIndex] = [factoryFunction]() { accept(factoryFunction); };
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5d93b7890c8e63d)

In this example, `FunctionTraits` uses partial specialization to figure out the return type and argument types of a function-like thing (assuming it doesn't have multiple overloads of `operator()`).  `ArgsTuple` then uses partial-specialization to build a tuple of `shared_ptr`s to pass to that function-like thing.

This allows `package` and `accept` to accept any type and figure out `WidgetType` and `Dependencies` using `FunctionTraits` and `ArgsTuple`.

Comment: Interesting. This approach, however, makes it difficult to tell what FactoryFunction is supposed to look like. Aside from the name, it's not  even clear that factoryFunction should be a functor; at least, not without reading the whole function. If I edit your demo to try to accept a Foo instead of a std::shared_ptr<Foo> on line 86, I get some hard to read errors (not that any of the other solutions are better), and I'm able to return a shared_ptr without any error at all! I was under the impression that concepts were designed to solve just these kinds of issues. Could they be incorporated?

Comment: Yes, you could create a concept that limits what can be passed for FactoryFunction.  Even some static_asserts could be helpful if you’re using a compiler that doesn’t support concepts.

Comment: You don't have any `noexcept` function/`operator()` specializations, nor ref-qualified `operator()`. The standard library already implements this with the [deduction guides for `std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides), so you can instead do `template<typename T> struct FunctionTraits : FunctionTraits<decltype(std::function{std::declval<T>()})> {};` `template<typename Ret, typename... Args> struct FunctionTraits<std::function<Ret(Args...)>> { using ReturnType = Ret; using ArgumentTypes = std::tuple<Args...>; };`